# Engagement value assignment to group or multiple pages

Tags: experience-analytics

How to set up an engagement value to multiple pages?

**Example:**

Assign the same value to all "product pages view" or all "add to cart" event

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar development whereby pages that the user has visited, the should receive the same engagement value.

First, I had to keep track of the pages that the user visited. Those were stored in the `PageEvents` in MongoDB. Each time a user visited a page, I triggered the below code to register the event.

```
public void CreateViewContentEvent(Guid itemId)
{
    try
    {
        if (Tracker.IsActive && Tracker.Current != null)
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current, "Tracker.Current");

            if (Tracker.Current != null && Tracker.Current.Session != null && Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction != null)
            {
                string viewEventName = $"{itemId}_view";

                var itemPath = $"/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events/Content Events View/{viewEventName}";

                Item viewEventItem = Context.Database.GetItem(itemPath, Language.Parse("en"));

                if (viewEventItem != null)
                {
                    CreatePageEventWithGoal(viewEventName, "Viewed", itemId, viewEventItem.ID.ToGuid());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error($"Error on Content Click Event {ex.StackTrace} with message {ex.Message} + msg {msg}", "AnalyticsService");
    }
}

private static void CreatePageEventWithGoal(string eventName, string eventText, Guid itemId, Guid pageEventDefinitionId)
{
    PageEventData pageEventData = new PageEventData(eventName, pageEventDefinitionId)
    {
        ItemId = itemId,
        Data = itemId.ToString(),
        DataKey = itemId.ToString("B"),
        PageEventDefinitionId = pageEventDefinitionId,
        Text = eventText,
        Name = eventName
    };

    if (Tracker.Current.Contact != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Tracker.Current.Interaction.CurrentPage.Register(pageEventData);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Log.Error($"Error on register tracking... ", "CreatePageEventWithGoal");
        }
    }
}
```

The below statement is to fetch the pageEvents in Sitecore. Those gets generated on item saved.

```
var itemPath = $"/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events/Content Events View/{viewEventName}";
```

Once I have the `view` events registered into MongoDB, I had implemented a custom Aggregation Processor to aggregate the data into a custom table.

A visit is a collection of PageEvents. So, to be able to add the same value to user view stream, when you loop through the `PageEvents`, you need to set the same visit value. Below is a code snippet I have used in my custom aggregator to retrieve the data from mongoDb to push it to a custom table in the analytics database.

```
private readonly IDictionary<string, string> typeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Viewed", "View" },
    { "Clicked", "Click" }
};

protected override void OnProcess(AggregationPipelineArgs args)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

    try
    {
        VisitData visit = args.Context.Visit;

        List<Guid> tempList = new List<Guid>();

        if (visit.Pages == null || visit.Pages.Count <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        ContentPerformance contentPerformance = null;

        foreach (PageData page in visit.Pages)
        {
            if (page.PageEvents == null || page.PageEvents.Count <= 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var pageEvents = page.PageEvents.Where(pe => !pe.Text.IsNullOrEmpty()).ToList();

            IEnumerable<PageEventData> relevantPageEvents = new List<PageEventData>();

            if (pageEvents.Any())
            {
                relevantPageEvents = pageEvents.Where(pe => this.typeMap.ContainsKey(pe.Text)).ToList();
            }

            if (relevantPageEvents.Any())
            {
                foreach (PageEventData pageEvent in relevantPageEvents)
                {
                    Guid? patternId = null;

                    using (var context = GetSearchIndex("my index name").CreateSearchContext())
                    {
                        var itemId = new ID(pageEvent.ItemId);

                        var content = context.GetQueryable<ContentBox>().FirstOrDefault(w => w.ItemId == itemId);

                        ContentPerformanceKey contentPerformanceKey = new ContentPerformanceKey
                        {
                            ItemId = pageEvent.ItemId,
                            PatternName = patternName
                        };

                        ContentPerformanceValue contentPerformanceValue = new ContentPerformanceValue();

                        bool notYetProcessed = !tempList.Contains(pageEvent.PageEventDefinitionId);

                        if (notYetProcessed)
                        {
                            contentPerformanceValue.Visits = 1;
                            contentPerformanceValue.Value = visit.Value;

                            tempList.Add(pageEvent.PageEventDefinitionId);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            contentPerformanceValue.Visits = 0;
                        }

                        if (contentPerformance == null)
                        {
                            contentPerformance = args.GetFact<ContentPerformance>();
                        }

                        contentPerformance.Emit(contentPerformanceKey, contentPerformanceValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error($"[Perso] Error occured in Content Performance: StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}. Message: {ex.Message}. InnerException: {ex.InnerException}", this);
    }
}
```

You may need to change the above to accommodate your requirement. You can read more from my post about [Sitecore Aggregation Process](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/sitecore-analytics-aggregators/)